# Path issues with pkgutil.iter_modules() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, path-separator

I'm trying to dynamically import Python modules that match a pattern at runtime. The modules are located inside a Python package.

The function I use to find the modules is:

```
def load_modules_from_dir(dirname, pattern=""):
    modules = []
    for importer, package_name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([dirname]):
        if re.search(pattern, package_name):
            full_package_name = '%s.%s' % (dirname, package_name)
            if full_package_name not in sys.modules:
                module = importer.find_module(package_name).load_module(full_package_name)
                modules.append(module)
    return modules
```

I call it as follows:

```
module_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
modules = utils.load_modules_from_dir(module_dir, "jscal$")
```

On Linux it finds all modules, but on Windows it doesn't find any modules at all. If I print `dirname` in function `load_modules_from_dir`, I get: `H:\temp\linx\dist\calibrate\dcljscal`

I've reproduced it in Python shell on Windows and nailed it down to the path delimiter. The following finds nothing:

```
>>> for x in pkgutil.iter_modules(['H:\temp\linx\dist\calibrate\dcljscal']):print x
...
>>>
```

If I replace the Windows path separator with the Linux one, it works:

```
>>> for x in pkgutil.iter_modules(['H:/temp/linx/dist/calibrate/dcljscal']):print x
...
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9C60>, 'demojscal', True)
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9C60>, 'dx2cremjscal', True)
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9C60>, 'linxjscal', True)
>>>
```

It also works if I replace `\` with `\\`, basically escaping the Windows path separator:

```
>>> for x in pkgutil.iter_modules(['H:\\temp\\linx\\dist\\calibrate\\dcljscal']):print x
...
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9E68>, 'demojscal', True)
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9E68>, 'dx2cremjscal', True)
(<pkgutil.ImpImporter instance at 0x00AD9E68>, 'linxjscal', True)
>>>
```

It seems that the path generated by `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is not portable.
I would expect that `os.path.join()` would give me a proper path that I can use unaltered in `pkgutil.iter_modules()`. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Python 2.7.11 on Windows XP.

Comment: Staring at `'\t'` doesn't raise any alarms for you?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, you are right. If I replace `\t` with `\\t`, it also works in Python shell. But you set me thinking. The path returned by `os.path.join()` must already contain the escaped version of the path. When I print parameter `dirname` in function `load_modules_from_dir`, I get: `H:\temp\linx\dist\calibrate\dcljscal` and not `H:  emp\linx\dist\calibrate\dcljscal`. The question now is why does it not work in `pkgutil.iter_modules()` ?

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))` makes no sense. Use `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: @eryksun Both `os.path.join()` and `os.path.abspath()` give the same result on my system. Thanks for your help. You pointed me in the right direction with the `\t`.

Comment: Yes, but joining a path of one string to create an absolute path is not the intended effect of `os.path.join`. Use the function that's obviously intended for what you want to do. Don't rely on a side effect of an unrelated function.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: There is no answer to this problem. Strings representing path names can always contain special characters that can bite you at any time.

There are a lot of SE post that try to give a solution. Most of them fix a special case and don't work in general. There is no consensus about what the best approach is. See:
- [Unpredictable results from os.path.join in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4982105/4459346)
- [Python windows path slash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19065115/4459346)
- [Path Separator in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13337552/4459346)
- [Windows path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/4459346)
- [mixed slashes with os.path.join on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16333569/4459346)
- [Why not os.path.join use os.path.sep or os.sep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12086224/4459346)

This blog post is also worth mentioning because the writer uses a slightly different approach to bring his point across: [backslashes-in-windows-filenames](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/)

A pragmatic way to handle path names is to replace the Windows path delimiter with the Linux one: `path_name = path_name.replace('\\', '/')`
Python on Windows XP and later versions of Windows have no problem with `C:/tab/newline/return/012/x012`.

Only when you have to print or record the path, you can use `os.path.normpath()` to convert the path to the representation of the OS or platform you are running Python on.

Comment: It would be a very bad bug if `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))` yielded a filepath that somehow reinterpreted `\t` as a tab. Generally only the *compiler* does that for *string literals*.

Comment: You can't always use slash in place of backslash. An extended path prefixed by ``\\?\`` requires backslash. This prefix bypasses the normal path processing in order to exceed the 260 character path limit. All Windows does is replace ``\\?\`` with the NT DOS devices prefix ``\??\`` before making the system call, and in the NT kernel namespace, *only backslash* is a path delimiter. Also, if you're creating a commandline to run another program with subprocess, the program may treat slashes as option switches.